# Fixpoints of gradient of monotone increasing, concave function

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus, systems-of-equations

Suppose we have a system of equations:

$$
x_1 = f_1(x_1, ..., x_n) \\
x_2 = f_2(x_1, ..., x_n) \\
... \\
x_n = f_n(x_1, ..., x_n)
$$

where the $f_i$ are components of the gradient ${\nabla}f$ for a monotone increasing, concave function $f$, so $f_i > 0$ and $\frac{{\partial}f_i}{{\partial}x_i}\leq 0$.

Does the system of equations necessarily have a solution? And is it unique if it exists?

I feel like there must be some application of a multivariate version of the Intermediate Value Theorem or Brouwer's Fixed Point Theorem that would be useful here...

Answer (score 0):

I think I have the answer to the uniqueness question.

Let $g = f + h$ where $h(x_1, ..., x_n) = -\frac{1}{2}\Sigma_i x_i^2$

Then $g$ is a strictly concave function, because it is the sum of a concave and a strictly concave function. And stationary points of concave functions are in general global maxima, so uniqueness follows by taking the derivative of $g$.